# How to get current unix epoch time in python that does not go backwards due to system clock backset

Tags: python, linux, time, unix-timestamp, system-clock

I am using python time module where I get the current unix time with `time.time()`. However, I am noticing that when I get current time and compare it to a previous `time.time()` call, the value is lower.

the alternative to this is to use `time.monotonic()` since it ensures an increase in time always. However Its return value starting point is undefined meaning that is not unix time.

Is there some other call (or module) that gets me a monotonic unix Time or do I have to get current date and time and convert it manually?

Comment: Sounds like a contradiction. What are you using the time for?

Comment: @Ry- I want to get time at 2 different instance in my code and find the difference. As long as time.monotonic() always continues with the same starting point even when I quit program then I can use that. But I don't know if it does that.

Comment: It’s not specifically documented on the Python side, but I’d say it’s a safe assumption. Its implementations on both POSIX and Windows systems have that guarantee. (To clarify: not across reboots, though.)